# jsonschema validation for $ref in node

Tags: npm, jsonschema

I have written validation for jsonschema using the npm jsonschema package. There is $ref included in my json schema, which has definitions defined below. But I am not able to reach that definitions when I use the function validate of jsonschema. Can some please help here.

For eg: I have schema like this

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "schemes": [
      "https"
    ],
{
"responses": {
            "200": {
              "description": "successful operation",
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/info"
              }
            }
}
"definitions": {
      "info": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Name",
            "required": true
          }
}
}
}
```

I have to validate the json response against the info definitions. Please help.

Comment: Welcome! You're going to have to show some code to help us understand what you're doing here. Also it's worth noting that Swagger / OpenAPI is not the same as JSON Schema, so you may have some misconceptions here.

Comment: I have converted the yml file to json schema. I have to check the response eg: {"name": "aaa"} against the schema. Now how can I check directly. I have to go to responses->200-> to its definitions. I am using validate function of jsonschema

Comment: Sure, but you're still going to need to show us some code, because there are 100 different ways you could do that.

Comment: Is it wrong to convert yaml file to json schema?

Comment: No, but there are many ways to do what you have said you have done. As such, for anyone to give you help, to identify the problem, you need to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is the code I have written for now. I am going directly to definitions and fetching the schema. But I don't want in this way. I want in systematic way.

var Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;
var v = new Validator();
const schema = require('./schema.json');
const value = {
    "status": 200,
    "body": {
        "name": "hello",
    }
}
console.log(v.validate(value.body, schema.definitions["customer-info"]));

Comment: You need to edit your question to include your code, and you need to provide enough code for someone else to run and reach the same issue you have found.

Comment: The json schema:

Comment: A Swagger / OpenAPI file is not the same as having a JSON Schema. You have a Swagger file there, not a JSON Schema file. You might want to look for Swagger tooling rather than JSON Schema tooling. Putting a Swagger document into a JSON Schema library isn't going to work.

Comment: If you don't want to use Swagger, as in you're not interested in the API definition, and only want to use JSON Schema to validate your payload JSON data, I might be able to help.

Comment: Can you suggest any swagger tooling.

If i want to continue in json schema, how will I be able to achive?

Comment: You can find an index of tooling at https://openapi.tools - If you wanted to use JSON Schema, you would have to define your schema for each payload you want to validate. I'd recommend starting at https://json-schema.org/learn/ to learn about how to write JSON Schema.

Comment: If I want to use direct yaml file and validate the api. How is it possible in node?

Comment: I feel that is outside of the scope of this question.You may find that question has already be answered on Stack Overflow before. I'd recommend using the sites search functionality to find out.